# Designing a circuit that converts rage of currents to a range of voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier

Using only resistors, ideal op amps, ideal sources... convert current of range \$4-20\:mA\$  to \$0-10V\$ voltage.

This is a homework question and I'm not quite sure what's the task. One way I could solve this is by using an ideal op amp and setting the rail voltages to \$0V\$ and \$10V\$. Can you suggest, or give an example of a better solution?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5CrUo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you show us a circuit that you attempted?  This website is not to solve homework problems.

Comment: I will draw it. Basically, I set some limit voltage on - and once the voltage on +, determined by the current, goes above that, the output goes to 10V.

Comment: No, the question is related to linearly solving an input that varies between 4 and 20 mA and produces an output that maps the output range of 0V to 10V linearly. I'll also add that you need one ideal voltage source and one resistor to achieve this (no op-amps).

Comment: Your proposed solution is not going to be correct.  If the op amps are supposed to be ideal, they will not saturate. You need to think about a graph where y=0 when x=.004 and y=10 when x=.02.

Comment: @owg60 Hold on. It won't saturate? In any scenario?

Comment: @Andyaka And so, I've designed my first circuit. Thanks.

Comment: Opamps normally have some form of feedback. Your circuit doesn't. Your circuit will act as a comparator - output near the negative rail when the input is less than 4mA, output near the positive rail when it's more.  Try adding feedback. Or try something different: there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Start with a transfer function with gain and offset for I to V then pick a suitable Vref

Comment: #offtopic.. Rage of Currents is an epic name for a movie/video game..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOuEDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think this is alright.

Comment: Not bad. Provided all of the input current flows through the resistor (and voltage source), this will work.  If any current flows out through Vout, that would cause a problem - but you could fix that, if necessary, with an opamp.

Comment: Yeah that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @JackB I was just about to post a question about this. I just use ideal op amps to transport divided voltage to someplace else?

Comment: One of the features of an ideal opamp is that no current flows into the inputs.  So if you connect Vout to one of the inputs of an opamp, it will make sure all the current goes the right way.  You then need to sort out the feedback to have a gain of 1. There is a very simple way of doing that, called "a buffer"